# Does C++ range-based `for` make copies?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11

I studying C++ and I am trying to understand range-based for loops.
Consider the following code

```
std::array<int,5> items{1,2,3,4,5};

for(int item: items){
   std::cout << std::setw(10) << item;
}
std::cout << std::endl;

for(int item: items){
   item++;
   std::cout << std::setw(10) << item;
}
std::cout << std::endl;

for(int item: items){
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << item;
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

It prints

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5
```

Thus, I understand that `item` takes the value of the corresponding element. This makes me wonder what happens with more complicated types. My guess is that `item`is a local variable that takes a copy of the corresponding element in `items`. Does that mean that if items is an array of larger objects, say

`std::array<MyObject,5> items`

the for loop takes a copy of each element?

(p.s., I know that I can change the value of the original item using `int& item: items`).

Comment: Yes, `int item : ...` makes a copy of each element. Yes, it can expensive for more complex types, that's why you often see `const MyType &item : ...` or `const auto &item : ...`.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176127/12002570) in the dupe: [Range based loop: get item by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176104/range-based-loop-get-item-by-value-or-reference-to-const)

Comment: Also [Why doesn't range-based for loop modifiy container elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872548/why-doesnt-range-based-for-loop-modifiy-container-elements)

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: It's not the `for` loop that makes the copy; it's the `int item`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default it copies the elements. But when taking a reference to the items you get, well, a reference and the values *will* be changed.

```
for(int &item: items){
   item++;
}
```

When using objects you avoid calling the copy constructor this way.

Copy constructor called.

```
for (Object item: items) { }
```

No copy constructor called

```
for (Object &item: items) { }
```

When you need the performance of no copy constructor calling but you dont want to change the objects, make them const.

```
for (const Object &item: items) { }
```